# How can i get the AWS signature token to upload a converted file with AutoDesk Forge API?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, autodesk-forge

I'm developing a feature in my web app to convert some .dwg stored in an s3 bucket to pdf with AutoDesk Forge API.

This is the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/tutorials/convert-dwg-to-pdf/) that I'm following

With GDrive I can make it work, but I can't if I use S3 as Output
I think it's because I need the signature token of AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way with S3 would be `signed URL` so our service can have anonymous access temporarily w/o a token to upload the outputs - see details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

And see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to obtain an access token for your S3 buckets to put in the header authorization option of your workitem payload.